# Grouped income data in Stata or SAS

Tags: data-transformation, stata, sas

I have an income distribution dataset which I am attempting to manipulate in Stata (or SAS).

I need to come up with a table listing the number of households earning between one income level and another. The income levels are regularly spaced, say at $10,000 intervals for example.

In other words, for $i=30,000$, I want to know the number of households $H_i$ receiving between 20,000 and 30,000.  And I want to know this for each i, at 10,000 dollar intervals, from 10,000 up to oh let's say 280,000.

$H_i=\int_{i-10000}^{i}f(x)\: dx$

$(0 < i\leq280000)$

(Where f(x) is the underlying density function representing households plotted along the y-axis, and x is income level, plotted along the x-axis. The distribution will have the skewed (lognormal-like) shape typical of income distributions.)

Does anyone know the Stata (or SAS) command that would give me this info? In Stata I can get the income at each percentile of the population using the "centile" command, but this doesn't quite give me what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Stata, assuming each case is a household,

```
gen i = autocode(x, 28, 0, 280000)
tab i
```

If cases represent multiple households, use weights with the `tab` command.

The help for `autocode` can be found under `functions|programming functions`.

Comment: @whuber --Thanks!  However the "tab i" is not doing the trick.  I mean it's not summing the casenumbers (represented along the y axis) between income levels $i$ and $i-1$ along the x axis.  (Casenumbers are households, so no need for weighting).

Comment: @whuber    Aha.  The following command gives me the number of households (case numbers) between two income levels: `count if dpi<30000 & dpi>20000`.  But this will be tedious to do from 0 to 280,000 at intervals of 10,000.  Is there any way to do this more quickly?

Comment: @whuber. Via the second argument of the `autocode` function you have to specify the number of intervals you want to create, rather than the width of the intervals. Thus, here you would have to type `gen i = autocode(x, 28, 0, 280000)` or `gen i = autocode(x, 27, 10000, 280000)`, depending on whether you start at 0 or 10000.

Comment: @lejohn Thank you!  I tested this code but copied the command incorrectly.  I'll edit the reply to fix the mistake.

Comment: @Ben what's the matter with `tab i`?  It works for me.  The output gives frequencies (those are the counts you want), percent, and cumulative percent.  If you need more than that, or you need to post-process the output, use `collapse` or `contract`.

Comment: @whubber Thanks, now it works.  Don't know what I was doing wrong.  Any idea how to change the interval length from 10000 to something else?

Comment: @lejohn Thanks.  The invform etc. code works well.  Not clear to me if the sum of case numbers is at the top of the interval or the bottom.  I assume it's at the top.

Comment: @Ben A reliable way to match recoded values to original values is to plot them (as a scatterplot or side-by-side boxplots) or summarize them (broken down by recoded value or, on occasion, by cross-tabulating them).  That will tell you definitively and convincingly what each recoded value corresponds to.  Noting that 10000 = 280000/28, all you need to is change either the "28" or the "280000" to change the interval to any desired value.

Answer (score 2):

In Stata, you can achieve this as follows:

```
clear
set seed 99
set obs 1000
gen inc = 10000 * exp(invnorm(uniform()))
gen lb = floor(inc/10000) * 10000
tabulate lb
```

This code creates left-bounded intervals, i.e. including the lower bound, but excluding the upper bound.

If you prefer the `count` approach, you can use the following code:

```
forvalues n = 0(10000)280000 {
    count if inrange(inc, `n', `n' + 10000)
}
```

Note that the `inrange` function refers to left-bounded intervals too.

If you need a table to be inserted in a document, you can add the following lines:

```
collapse (count) N = inc, by(lb)
gen interval = "[" + string(lb) + ";" + string(lb + 10000) + ")" 
list interval N, sep(0) noobs
```

Answer (score 1):

In SAS something like this could work:

```
data new;
 set old;
 inccat = floor(income/10000);
run;

proc freq data = new;
 table inccat;
run;
```